# ¿Cómo puedo convertir un texto a mayúsculas con React Native?

Tags: react-native

Tengo una cadena del tipo:

```
<Text> {mi_cadena} </Text>
```

y me gustaría que el valor me apareciera en mayúscula automáticamente. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

También puedes usar el estilo en elementos Text para este fin de la siguiente forma:

```
<Text style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase'}}>
    This text should be uppercased.
</Text>
```

Las opciones disponibles son 'none', 'uppercase', 'lowercase', 'capitalize'.
[Documentación](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props#texttransform)

Comment: Qué bueno, no sabía que existiera este estilo.

Comment: Si, resulta interesante cuando parte de la interfaz se genera de forma dinámica puesto que permite personalizar elementos de forma independiente.

Answer (score 5):

¡Sí! Usa [`.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objectes_globals/String/toUpperCase) de JavaScript:

```
<Text> {mi_cadena.toUpperCase()} </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma me arregle el problema. "En en TextInput se agrega autoCapitalize="characters" de esa manera me sirvió, recomiendo hacer pruebas en un dispositivo físico ya que en los emuladores suele presentar fallos"

Comment: Esa funcion solo serviria para `TextInput` y no para `Text`